# How to have exactly one entry per enum variant in collection (HashMap, array,...)?

Tags: rust, enums, data-modeling

### The problem

I have an enum in a module A of my code that I use in a module B to store configurations according to its variants.

Module A:

```
enum FragmentType {
  Content,
  Structure,
}
```

Module B:

```
use crate::module_a::FragmentType;

enum ConfigurationStrategy {
  Any(String),
  Parenthood {
    with_child: String,
    without_child: String,
  },
}

struct Configuration {
  default: HashMap<FragmentType, ConfigurationStrategy>,
  custom: HashMap<FragmentType, ConfigurationStrategy>,
}
```

With this code `Configuration` can have an empty HashMap for its `default` field, which is problematic as it will be the fall-back for custom configuration absence.

I would like to ensure with Rust type system that the `default` field is "complete". I didn't find any way to do it with HashMap (is there any ?), so I searched a workaround.

### The workaround

I found a way to do it by using an array for `default`.

Module A:

```
enum FragmentType {
  Content,
  Structure,
}

const NB_VARIANT_FRAGMENT_TYPE: usize = 2; 
//I didn't found nicer way to have this value without nightly `mem::variant_count`
```

Module B:

```
use crate::module_a::{FragmentType, NB_VARIANT_FRAGMENT_TYPE};

enum ConfigurationStrategy {
  Any(String),
  Parenthood {
    with_child: String,
    without_child: String,
  },
}

struct Configuration {
  default: [ConfigurationStrategy; NB_VARIANT_FRAGMENT_TYPE],
  custom: HashMap<FragmentType, ConfigurationStrategy>,
}

impl Configuration {
  fn default_strategy(&self, _type: FragmentType) -> ConfigurationStrategy {
    match _type {
      FragmentType::Content => self.default[0],
      FragmentType::Structure => self.default[1],
    }
  }
}
```

With it I ensure that there will be the right amount of configurations (as long as `NB_VARIANT_FRAGMENT_TYPE` is well maintained) that I can access with `config.default_strategy(FragmentType::Content);`.

But I'm wondering if there is other (and preferably better) ways to achieve the same result ?

Answer (score 1):

> But I'm wondering if there is other (and preferably better) ways to achieve the same result ?

Using a function to compute the fallback would require-ish it to be complete (the implementation could still be partial).

Something like https://docs.rs/enum-map/latest/enum_map/ might also be an option, I would assume it requires the map to be complete since it doesn't expose a `get` method (only `Index`).

Incidentally and somewhat unrelated, `_type` is bad style: in Rust, a `_` prefix means the item is named but opted out of the "unused local" warning. While you can't use `type` because it's a keyword, better alternatives would be:

- `t`, the function is very short so the variable is hardly essential
- renaming `type` to a different word of similar meaning e.g. `kind`, `category`, ...
- `type_`, a `_` suffix does not have the semantic connotation of a prefix
- `r#type`, the `r#` prefix "escapes" the identifier, I would not recommend that one, that's mostly useful when interacting with external systems which impose the naming

Comment: I thought of the filler function, but I wanted the completeness to be assured at compile time (not sure it's necessary, but it seems to be a good practice). I've encountered enum_map in my research, but for this single case I preferred to avoid adding new dependency. (maybe I'll reconsider). Thanks for information on `_type` by the way.

Comment: Just to add another alternative, `typ` is another common name, and also has the neat little fact of being German for “type” :D